# form send button is already pre clicked when the jquery function is loaded

Tags: php, jquery

Suppose, a,b,c results are dynamically generated from database via echoing  `$scname` variable  and `showtablesc` is trigered on `onclick`. But except  first time clicked,  send button  on the form  is always seems pre clicked when I click on  any `a,b ,c` results.

My Php code is here:

```
   echo "<a  href='#$name' style='margin-left: 30px' onclick=showtablesc();>$scname</a><br>";
```

html goes here..

```
 <table id="jobs" style="display:none"  bgcolor="#0099FF" align="center"

     <tr  ><td> j tittle</td><td><input type="text" name="tittle" /></td></tr>
     <tr ><td><input type='button' value='send'  id="send"  /></td> </tr>
    </table>
```

jquery function goes here

```
function showtablesc(){

$('#jobs').show('fast');
$('#send').click(function(){
    $('#send').replaceWith("<em>sending...</em>");

    });
```

}

Comment: you can't have multiple elements with the same id! you give same ids to all echoed jobs buttons!

Comment: thanks @MateiMihai,plz do let me knw with the  how can i correctify.

Comment: @Deepak a,b ,c r the result coming from database.which when clicked,jobs form is shown

Answer (score 1):

It seems your tr has the class "jobs" and your button does. Meaning that JQuery will perform click on both and your tr is first in line to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<a  href=\"#$name\" class=\"my-link\" style=\"margin-left: 30px\">$scname</a><br />";

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a.my-link').click(function(){
        $('#jobs').show('fast').find('em').replaceWith('<input type="button" value="Send" class="jobs" />');
    });

    $('#jobs').on('click','input.jobs',function(){   
        $(this).replaceWith("<em>sending...</em>");   
    });   

});
```

Comment: thank u for ur help but i testd with this code, after  first click,again sending... appers instesd of send button

Comment: this is what `replaceWith` method is doing! It replace your button with `<em>sending...</em>`. Maybe you want to use `$(this).val('sending..')` instead of `replaceWith`?

Comment: thank u @matei for response. i want to show send button on the form every time results  a,b,c are being clicked.'sendiing....' must show only if the user will click on send button

Comment: I've edited my answer so when the `a.my-link` will be clicked the `em` will be replaced with `input.jobs`

Comment: ,thnk u,but now function is not being executed upon clicking the send button.send is not replaced with sending....

Comment: and now? I've added the `on` method

Answer (score 0):

Change your `HTML` block to this

```
<table id="jobs_table" style="display:none"  bgcolor="#0099FF" align="center">

 <tr class="jobs" >
    <td> j tittle</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="tittle" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr >
    <td><input type='button' value='send'  class="jobs_button"/></td> 
 </tr>
</table>
```

And your `Jquery` to

```
function showtablesc(){
   $('.jobs_button').removeAttr("id");

   $('.jobs_button').attr('id', 'send');
   $('#jobs_table').show('fast');
   $('#send').click(function(){
       $('#send').replaceWith("<em>sending...</em>");
   });
}
```

Comment: thanks,but problem is still there.Sending.. appers on secod click.

Comment: how are you loading content to `DOM` ? can you post the ajax block ?

Comment: results r  being retrieved via mysql select query.

Comment: looks like you are duplicating the forms. can you post your ajax which creates the form ?